# Android app crashes at start with "E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file" and "non-0 exit status"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat, dex

My app (still WIP) runs fine on different devices. But suddenly it refuses to start on Huawei Honor 7 (Android 6.0/EMUI 4.0.3). Logcat gives me the following:

> E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file:
> /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@myapp.mycomp.de.myapp-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex:
> Permission denied

followed by

> 07-12 19:23:49.223
> 11280-11280/myapp.mycomp.de.myapp W/art: Failed
> execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg
> --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/myapp.mycomp.de.myapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk
> --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@myapp.mycomp.de.myapp-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex)
> because non-0 exit status

This error occurs 9 times for `spli_lib_slice_N_apk.apk-parts` . I really have no idea, what it could be, especially since it run fine until today. I did no changes to the code. I also don't use any multidex, as far as I know.

Any hint is appreciated, Thank you!

**UPDATE JULY, 13TH 2017:**
I logged the app starts with a device on which it always works and I got the same "errors" as above. So it seems, that these messages may be normal... After this I had a look into the crash log of the faulty device and found the following lines shortly AFTER the errors I posted above:

> 07-12 20:30:35.985 3209-3421/? I/logserver: extract_appname, forward search, appname=myapp.mycomp.de.myapp
> 07-12 20:30:35.985 3209-3421/? I/logserver: get_fault_appname, appname=myapp.mycomp.de.myapp
> 07-12 20:30:35.987 3209-3420/? I/logserver: handle_notify_event, send msg [submit:trigger=0,bugtype=2,modulename=myapp.mycomp.de.myapp,level=1,testtype=NORMAL,path=/data/log/unzip/PLK-L01_PLK-L01C432B390_0000000000_20170712203035_crash,mode=1;]
> 07-12 20:30:36.014 21797-21899/myapp.mycomp.de.myapp I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
> 07-12 20:30:36.290 21797-21797/myapp.mycomp.de.myapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21797 SIG: 9

It seems the process gets killed by Sigkill 9, see also on SE here: [App dies with "Sending signal." but no exception or other info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420963/app-dies-with-sending-signal-but-no-exception-or-other-info)

But again I have no idea what causes this. After this, I cleared the app data within androids app-preferences and suddenly the app starts again. The investigation will continue...

Comment: PS: Clearing the device' dalvik-cache also didn't help

Comment: Do you have Instant Run enabled in Android Studio? If yes, try to disable it.

Comment: @AlexLipov Thank you, I just deployed a new build with disabled Intant Run. Since the misbehavior takes 1-2days to show, I will let you know the results in a couple of days.

Comment: UPDATE July 17th, 2017: I tried a build with disabled Instant Run (IR) and never experienced this behavior again. Not sure if IR has anything to do with this, but  I will give @AlexLipov an upvote , because it just works now ;-) Unluckily I do not own enough rep to close my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling instant run, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0/)

and then edit your main dex file, check out this [resource](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex/) on the android developer site to ensure you have the correct classes enabled in your main dex file