# How to disable Instant Run for Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After making a few changes I am getting an error

> Session 'app': Error Installing APKs

According to some it is because of Instant Run.

On the latest Stable Android Studio 3.0, under **Build, Execution, Deployment**  I don't have any option for Instant Run, even checked in the settings search. Any clue where I might be able to **disable** it?

Update 1: Tried reinstalling. No change.

Build number 171.4408382

Update 2: Gave reset a shot https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397632/1926621 still nothing.

Update 3: Not a duplicate. Must be something in the settings. A complete clean install/reset did it.

Screenshot of what I see:
[image]

Comment: You might want to post a screenshot of what you see in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment on your machine.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Updated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is an Android module? You are missing many things here that I see in my Android Studio's Settings.

Comment: @CommonsWare: It is just a normal Android studio. Didn't edit anything. What else should I try? I'll give reinstall a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

Comment: Have you tried **File Settings... (Ctrl + Alt + S)** as opposed to **Default settings?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally fixed!

As other users on Linux and such saw the Instant Run option in the settings, I tried reinstalling and resetting the installation, following https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397632/1926621

Removed all old settings, and installation of Android Studio( kept the SDK files). Changed the path. Opened the same project, and the options were now there!

Answer (score 54):

Go to `Android Studio Settings or Preferences (for MAC)` -> `Build,Execution,Deployment` -> `Instant Run.`

Then deselect the "Enable Instant Run" checkbox at the top.

**Linux Screenshot:**

[image: Android Studio 3.0 Settings, Showing Instant Run Options]

**Windows Screenshot:**

[image: Android Studio 3.0 Settings (Windows), Showing Instant Run Options]

For Mac go to Help in MenuBar and type 'preferences' 
or,
go to 'Android Studio -> Preferences' in MenuBar

[Mac ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcMjb.png)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed: It's the correct answer, though. See the screenshot. I get the same results on Linux and macOS; it's possible that somehow the Windows edition of Android Studio is broken, but that seems unliekly.

Comment: I am on the Windows edition indeed. 3.0 if that helps. Updated just a few days ago. Post updated with screenshot.

Comment: Tried reinstalling. No change. Do any of you get it on Windows ?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57880886/6114088 for AS 3.5+

Answer (score 54):

Instant Run is not a feature of Android Studio 3.5 (and later) any more and so cannot be disabled. 
In case you find an old guide recommending to disable it, you can ignore this instruction.
See here [1](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-studio-3-5-canary-apply-changes-instant-run-replacement/) and here [2](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-studio-project-marble-apply-changes-e3048662e8cd).

Comment: any way to turn the new Apply Changes thing off?  I keep seeing a pop-up informing me that my app was restarted without a reinstall -- I'd prefer something as close to a clean slate on the device as possible re: my app when running a build with updated code.  Several milliseconds shaved off iteration does not outweigh countless hours spent googling about tools-generated bugs...

Comment: I would have thought  this is always a manual process now. Maybe the target device must be also Android 8.0 at least. See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-studio-project-marble-apply-changes-e3048662e8cd

Answer (score 11):

Just make sure you go to **Android Studio -> Preferences** instead of **File -> Other settings -> default settings**.
Instant run should be there.

Answer (score 7):

Instant Run is removed from Android Studio 3.5 and added Apply Changes which works for Android 8 and above please follow the link for more https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html

[image: Apply Changes]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest/Laziest option for For mac would be CMD+SHIFT+A Search for instant run, click on relevant suggestion and uncheck the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Instant run is not a feature in Android Studio Bumblebee anymore.

Comment: This is already mentioned, with much more detail, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57880886/6045800)