# How to fix this error.?

Tags: android, android-studio

E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.aneeshas.t4trollers-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied`

The above mentioned is the error which I am getting while run my app. Please help me with a solution

[Please find the screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBy5W.jpg)

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: Please explain more the error. It would also be helpful if you added a screenshot

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Please help me to remove this error

Comment: [Disable Instant Run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46999669/5180017) in Android Studio and try again.

Comment: I already disabled the Instant Run. But still not working

Answer (score 0):

please add below dependency in app level build.gradel file.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

add below line  in sane file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

and last add application class like below

```
public class MyApplication extends MultidexApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
  }
}
```

and register your application class in manifest file.

Comment: MultiDex.install is unnecessary if you extends MultidexApplication (that can also be used directly)

Comment: Why did you post another same answer?

Comment: I tried the above solution.But still the same error exists.What to do then?