# Have to uninstall the app before running in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am using Xiomi Poco F1. When I run the app code in Android Studio to install the app in my phone, it asks me to uninstall the previously installed app which is very annoying. Is there a way to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if Instant Run is on. Make it off.

Follow this -

[How to disable Instant Run for Android Studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0)