# App is always restart after Run from Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1

My test device is Samsung S9 - Android 10

My App is targeting API 29, support API version is 29.0.3

The thing is when I hit the Run button in Android Studio. The project always build successfully but the app on my phone doesn't get restarted therefore the new code never get applied.

This behavior only happens after I update to Android Studio 4.1

Anyone have any idea how to fix this because restarting the app manually is ready frustrating.

Comment: Try disabling "instant run". See this question for assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0

Comment: "Instant Run" doesn't exist anymore, it was replaced with Apply Changes https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html

Comment: See comment #3 here. looks like its a known issue with 4.1.1 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173912349